# Google's html5 shiv not rendering placeholders?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, placeholder

I have a form which the client wants the labels inside the input box and I decided to use HTML 5's placeholder and Google's html5shiv, instead of the old javascript. My placeholders, however, don't seem to work properly in IE, which is what I was using the shiv for. Here is the code:

Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Shiv:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Full Name..." />
    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Your Telephone Number..." />
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address..." />
    <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" placeholder="Your Enquiry or Comments..."></textarea>
    <p class="midpadLeft green_Button_margin_2"><span class="green_Button_2"><a href="javascript: document.contactForm.submit();" target="_self" class="green_Button_2">Submit Enquiry <img src="images/mid-envelope.png" alt="Submit"/></a></span></p>

</form>
```

Any ideas as to why it's not working?

Revision:

Using code suggested in the comments below, I have changed my code to the following, but it is still not working.

Script including (the contents of that script was copied directly from [here](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js/blob/master/Placeholders.js)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/placeholders.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

DOM ready event listener:

```
<body onload="Placeholders.init(true);">
```

Comment: There does not seem to be any reference to placeholder attributes [in the code](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/tree/master/src). Is html5shiv actually supposed to shim them?

Comment: As far as I'm aware html5shiv doesn't do anything for the `placeholder` attribute. There are various shims available though (mostly jQuery)... see [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for a list, or [my own attempt](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) (which doesn't require jQuery)

Comment: @JamesAllardice I have tried your code, but it's not working. Please see revision

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung - See what revision?

Comment: The one I just added, sorry, I should have done that in the opposite order

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung - Yeah that would have been better :) Check the console, do you see any errors? Or do the placeholders just not appear at all?

Comment: I can't see any errors, they just don't appear

Comment: @JamesAllardice It's fixed now, it appears I missed a semi colon in the copying

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung - Glad you got it working :)

Comment: @JamesAllardice It's a very good script, thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The HTML5 Shiv simply enables styling for previously unknown elements in IE. The most recent version does a few things extra, like patching `document.createElement`, but other than that it doesn’t polyfill anything.

If you want to emulate `placeholder`, use a placeholder polyfill. I’ve written one in jQuery plugin format, if you’re interested: http://mths.be/placeholder

Use it as follows:

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

Here’s a demo: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Btw, you should be using `<label>` instead of `@placeholder` if the text is “Your Full Name” etc.

Comment: I am running into a problem using asp:TextBox with this script. The Control has an asp RequiredValidator control tied to it, which is failing to catch no value, resulting in a post back. Removing the placeholder plugin fixes this. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Todd Northrop's jquery.watermark NuGet package too.

```
//polyfill placeholder in older browsers
var inputs = $('input, textarea');

$.each(inputs, function (i, itm) {
    var input = $(itm);
    input.watermark(input.attr('placeholder'));
});
```

I have compared both methods provided, and watermark seems to cope with Password inputs better, but its not quite as easy to set up watermark.